# What was the first full-length film that was a musical?

Tags: cinema-history, musical

What was the first full-length film that was a musical? I presume it would have to be after talkies became a thing.

Comment: Wouldt the Jazz Singer (1927) count as a musical? It's a biopic, but so are other, later muscals; and it's got six songs. There arent't any dance numbers, if I remember correctly, but at least the last song is performed on a big stage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_film#The_first_musicals), it is [The Jazz Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jazz_Singer).

> **The Jazz Singer is a 1927 American musical film. The first feature-length motion picture with synchronized dialogue sequences**, its release heralded the commercial ascendance of the "talkies" and the decline of the silent film era. Directed by Alan Crosland and produced by Warner Bros. with its Vitaphone sound-on-disc system, the film, featuring six songs performed by Al Jolson, is based on a play of the same name by Samson Raphaelson, adapted from one of his short stories "The Day of Atonement".

Answer (score 4):

[image]

THE JAZZ SINGER (1927) was intended to be a silent film that would showcase the Al Jolson musical numbers and otherwise would have a recorded musical accompaniment. Al Jolson ad-libbed some unscripted lines like "You ain't heard nothing yet!", which made the film a sensation. There had been talking short films before using the Vitaphone disk system (usually musical shorts) and the Fox Movietone sound-on-film system (usually newsreels).

Warner Brothers released another part-talkie musical with Jolson titled THE SINGING FOOL in 1928. The first all-talking feature musical that was released was M-G-M's THE BROADWAY MELODY (1929), which won the Academy Award for the best film of 1929.

Answer (score -2):

The Jazz Singer is a musical and is the first feature length film that uses synchronized sound but it's only a partial sound picture. If you're looking for the first feature length musical that is not just a partial sound film the earliest I know of is The Broadway Melody (of 1929) which premiered in early February of 1929.

Comment: Good information but this was already mentioned in [another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/61272/101022) to this question.